# How do I convert a column of Texts with hyperlink into the text URL in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example,

The column of Company names that are hyperlinked
Company A
Company B 
...

converted to

URL of company A
URL of company B
...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you show us what you have tried, and where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I have no programming background so I have been trying to copy and paste special with no avail. I'm trying to extract the hyperlinks to url so that I can try parsing data from a list of 500 websites.

Comment: so you have a column of cells which are all hyperlinked, is that correct?

Comment: yes. so I wish to have a column of cells with only the url links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little piece of code should take the value of the hyperlink and put it into a column on a new sheet:

```
Sub RemoveHyperlinks()
    Dim Cell As Range

    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    Set Cell = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    i = 0

    Do Until i = Cell.Hyperlinks.Count
    If Cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, 1).Value = Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(k).Address
    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1
    End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if this is a super basic question, but where should I run this code and is there anything I need to edit?

Comment: you need to put t into a new module (record a new macro then go into the developer and edit the macro you recorded) you will need to rename the workbooks and sheets to whatever your workbook and sheets are called

Comment: I've tried to run it but there was an Error 9: subscript out of range and it pointed me to debug the line 'Set Cell = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange' But the workbook and sheet I referred to is correct.

Comment: Hi @scb998, I think there is a slight error in the code you provided as the list of urls generated appears to be the first url of the list, but however when I click through the others, it brings me to the correct hyperlinks. Is there a way to salvage this error?

Comment: It's okay now! I found the bug, it should be Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, 1).Value = Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(k).Address

Comment: @AGoh - yes you are correct! Ive updated the code to take that into account.